# Is pandas a local-only library

Tags: python, pandas

I recently started coding, but took a brief stint. I started a new job and I’m under some confidential restrictions. I need to make sure python and pandas are secure before I do this—I’ll also be talking with IT on Monday

I was wondering if pandas in python was a local library, or does the data get sent to or from elsewhere?  If I write something in pandas—will the data be stored somewhere under pandas?

The best example of what I’m doing is best found on a medium article about stripping data from tables that don’t have csv Exports.

https://medium.com/@ageitgey/quick-tip-the-easiest-way-to-grab-data-out-of-a-web-page-in-python-7153cecfca58

Comment: Did you try disabling your network and running pandas? You would know the answer at once.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `DataFrame` out of a dict, doing vectorized operations on its rows, printing out slices of it, etc. are all completely local. I'm not sure why this matters. Is your IT department going to say, "Well, this looks fishy—but some random guy on the internet says it's safe, so forget our policies, we'll allow it"? But, for what it's worth, you have this random guy on the internet saying it's safe.

However, Pandas *can* be used to make network requests. Some of [the IO functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) can take a URL instead of a filename or file object. Some of them can also use another library that does so—e.g., if you have `lxml` installed, [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html), will pass the filename to `lxml` to open, and if that filename is an HTTP URL, `lxml` will go fetch it.

This is rarely a concern, but if you want to get paranoid, you could imagine ways in which it might be.

For example, let's say your program is parsing user-supplied CSV files and doing some data processing on them. That's safe; there's no network access at all.

Now you add a way for the user to specify CSV files by URL, and you pass them into `read_csv` and go fetch them. Still safe; there is network access, but it's transparent to the end user and obviously needed for the user's task; if this weren't appropriate, your company wouldn't have asked you to add this feature.

Now you add a way for CSV files to reference other CSV files: if column 1 is `@path/to/other/file`, you recursively read and parse `path/to/other/file` and embed it in place of the current row. Now, what happens if I can give one of your users a CSV file where, buried at line 69105, there's `@http://example.com/evilendpoint?track=me` (an endpoint which does something evil, but then returns something that looks like a perfectly valid thing to insert at line 69105 of that CSV)? Now you may be facilitating my hacking of your employees, without even realizing it.

Of course this is a more limited version of exactly the same functionality that's in every web browser with HTML pages. But maybe your IT department has gotten paranoid and clamped down security on browsers and written an application-level sniffer to detect suspicious followup requests from HTML, and haven't thought to do the same thing for references in CSV files.

I don't think that's a problem a sane IT department should worry about. If your company doesn't trust you to think about these issues, they shouldn't hire you and assign you to write software that involves scraping the web. But then not every IT department is sane about what they do and don't get paranoid about. ("Sure, we can forward this under-1024 port to your laptop for you… but you'd better not install a newer version of Firefox than 16.0…")

Comment: Thanks abarnert— they didn’t ask me write the program. I just know how I WOULD theoretically do it, but it’s a lot of manual entry that can be avoided.